# Query in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to replace this query in sql server ?

```
DELETE FROM student 
WHERE id=2 
 AND list_column_name='lastName' 
  OR list_column_name='firstName' 
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: You are trying to delete no more than 3 records, that match the WHERE clause?

Comment: You have not even provided an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ORDER BY` in your original query.

If you just want to delete an arbitary three records matching your `WHERE` you can use.

```
DELETE TOP(3) FROM student
WHERE  id = 2
       AND list_column_name = 'lastName'
        OR list_column_name = 'firstName';
```

For greater control of `TOP` (as ordered by what?) you need to use a CTE or similar.

Answer (score 1):

using CTE and TOP 3 where equal to LIMIT 3

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT TOP 3 Studentname
         FROM   student
         WHERE  id = 2
                AND list_column_name = 'lastName'
                 OR list_column_name = 'firstName')
DELETE FROM CTE
```

Comment: CTE its not excepting, does CTE means column name

Comment: can you tell me in which environment you are executing ?

Comment: You were missing a column list between `TOP 3` and `FROM`